Google Api's errorr on browser console
index.ts:171
   POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=AIzaSyA6QhXnrS2PXg7U5KN8ZNRu1Evd3G0OZ6U 400 (Bad Request)

I am working on firebase import and export for creating a form and stored the users data in dataBase and browser show the Bad request error of Google Api's on console over onClick the button and i am working with javascript not other language.
I want to know the reason of this error and how to solve this error

Where is the Javascript you are supposedly working with?
